# Copy values from a sheet to other sheet only into blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new on VBA and also on this site. I found and adapted this code to my needs,  but it copy only the first row from column A(sheet "Vectori") in the blank cells of "TABEL" sheet(column A), and i want to copy all values from column A(sheet "Vectori"), not only one.

```
Sub test()
    Dim myvalue As String
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Rows(Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    Worksheets("Vectori").Select

    myvalue = Range("A2").value

    Worksheets("TABEL").Select

    Range("A2").Select

    'go to first blank cell

    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    'write variable values into this blank row

    ActiveCell.value = myvalue


    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)).copy

    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: you have "Worksheets("Vectori").Select" but the varaible defined as "vector" do you need a new variable?"

Comment: in the "vector" variable i want to keep the values of the whole column, but starting from cell A2.

Comment: In one place you have VECTORI and the other VECTOR ...

Comment: i edited it..."Vectori" is the sheet that contains the values i need to paste in the "TABEL" sheet. sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the *Range* to suit your needs.

Replace:

```
Range("A2")
```

With:

```
Range("A2:Z100")
```

Just select the range that covers your entire data.

Comment: it doesn't work...and i want, if it's possible, to keep the values from A2 to the last used row

Answer (score 0):

I solved it :)

```
Sub test()

Dim thisarray As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim index As Integer
index = 1

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
thisarray = Worksheets("Vectori").Range("A2:A" & lastrow).value

While index <= UBound(thisarray)
        Worksheets("TABEL").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.value = thisarray(index, 1)
 index = index + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Have a nice day!